# Called WinForm not getting focus

Tags: c#, winforms, focus

In the form calling the 2nd form I have this code:

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
frmCalledForm frm = new frmCalledForm();
frm.Show();
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
```

And in the `Load()` event of frmCalledForm

```
this.TopMost = true;
this.BringToFront();
this.Activate();
```

I have the code calling the 2nd form in a button click event and at one point I open it programmatically based on certain conditions.

In both cases, the called form does not get focus, the calling form retains focus, even though it is minimized and then returned to normal.

I found the above code in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551074/why-wont-form-get-focus), and apparently it's working for him, but for some reason it's not working for me.

Due to Chris's comment about returning the calling form to Normal state, I commented that line out, but left the line minimizing the calling form.

Besides the fact that, to the user, the main form will suddenly disappear to his taskbar and stay there, which obviously doesn't make for a good user experience. But when I ran the program with the modified code, the main form went to the taskbar, and the called form opened, but **still did not have focus**. I was quite surprised to see that.

Comment: I suspect setting the first form's window state back to normal would make it grab the focus.

Comment: @Chris - thanks - see end of my question for what happened when I removed the line returning the calling form to Normal

Comment: Try setting the form's parent, ie: `frm.Parent = this;`

Comment: In that case go even further. Don't touch the window state of the first window at all + remove all the code in the second form's Load event. If that works, then start adding stuff back until it doesn't and you know what caused it..!

Comment: Do you have other lines of code after the one restoring the first form window?

Comment: @Steve. No I don't in both cases that I open the 2nd form, it is the last code in the respective methods.

Comment: @Chris - tried a few combinations - not messing with the state of the calling form, commenting/uncommenting the various lines in the called form. In all cases I got the same behavior: the called form opened on top/in front of the calling form but the 2nd form never got focus when called/opened

Comment: You understand that, if you just do `var frm = new frmCalledForm(); frm.Show();`, `frmCalledForm` will get activated and this doesn't require any further action, right? So, if this new Form is not activated (or deactivated, because it loses focus riight after), there's something else that is going on after you call `Show()` (in the calling code). I.e., this is not the code that can reproduce the behavior described. If something happens after `Show()` (in both Forms) - running tasks, timers, other events, that's what you need to post.

Comment: @Jimi - that makes total sense. I will go through my code to see if I can find anything that's happening after the `Show()` method is called (there are a few places it happens)